# Typo3: Use USER_INT with HMENU's special.value

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I'm just trying to compute, in my `page.typoscript` file, a value programmatically, using PHP code. This is what I've done:

```
        dataProcessing {
            1010 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            1010 {
                levels = 2
                special = directory
                special.value = USER_INT
                special.value {
                    userFunc = Vendor\Extension\Utils\NavigationBarUtils->getPlatformRootPid
                }
                as = menuMain
            }
         ... 
        }
```

And the method called is this one:

```
    public function getPlatformRootPid(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

When I load whatever page `menuMain` is null. The namespace is correct. Also, I've used methods like this to compute some other values in that same `page.typoscript` file, and they work.

When setting that value as `special.value = 1`, it works as expected.

Is it a problem with MenuProcessor's (i.e. HMENU) `special.value` and USER_INT? Are they incompatible somehow? Or am I missing something else here?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've figured out a way to do it:

```
1010 { 
  levels = 2
  special = directory
  special.value.postUserFunc = Vendor\Extension\Utils\NavigationBarUtils->getPlatformRootPid
  as = menuMain 
}
```

In effect it does what I wanted, set that value programmatically by calling a PHP method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed types.

`special.value` expects a value, which might get modified by `.stdWrap`functions.

you try to modify an attribute to be an object, which can't work.
you assigned the value (string) `USER_INT` and the stdWrap function `userFunc`, which does not exist.

if you want to use an object for a value you need to use `.cObject`. So your solution probably is:

```
1010 {
    levels = 2
    special = directory
    special.value.cObject = USER_INT
    special.value.cObject {
        userFunc = Vendor\Extension\Utils\NavigationBarUtils->getPlatformRootPid
    }
    as = menuMain
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I think I understand what the problem was now. The thing is that I've changed it as you've shown and it still not works. Do you have any clue of what be happening or how could I debug this? I never know how to debug TypoScript in the frontend.

Comment: the problem is the evaluation. not to every value `.stdWrap` is applied before the value is used. this depends on the PHP which evaluates the typoscript. I don't know whether the dataprocessor evaluates all attributes. In this way it is difficult to debug TypoScript. normally you look in the TSOB in Backend and set conditions accordingly. another option is the admin-panel. But you never know what the PHP is evaluating from the naked typoscript. therefore you need to debug the PHP.

Comment: Ah I see. Anyways, thanks to your comments I've figured out a way to do it:

```
1010 {
    levels = 2
    special = directory
                special.value.postUserFunc = Vendor\Extension\Utils\NavigationBarUtils->getPlatformRootPid
    as = menuMain
}
```

In effect it does what I wanted, set that value programmatically by calling a PHP method.
Thanks again.

Comment: make it an official answer to your question and accept it so others can see there is a working solution.